# Redis cluster marked down

Tags: redis-cluster

I do have redis cluster called 1a,1b,1c ,2a,2b,2c . Here a series are masters and b series are slaves . Due to instances issue both my 3a and 3b went down By that time we were seeing complete outage of the redis cluster. Not sure why other 2 masters still can serve the response . Can anyone please share more details of any additional configs to be set it up to avoid these issues ?

here trying to provide High availability of the redis cluster